# Can there be more than one proof for the limit as x approaches 3 of x squared equal 9?

Tags: limits

Can there be more than one proof for this question? An answer has been provided here and I can see that proof is valid: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/prove-that-limit-as-x-approaches-three-of-x-2-is-equal-to-9.704850/ but I want to know if the following alternate proof is valid too:

0 < |x−3|<δ
then

|x−3||x+3|<ε
|x−3| < ε/|x+3|
thus (preliminary assumption) δ=ε/|x+3|

Proof (substituting δ|x+3|=ε) :

|x−3||x+3|<δ|x+3|

|x−3||x+3|<(ε/|x+3|)*|x+3|

thus

|x−3||x+3|<ε

Comment: You could always do proof by contradiction or contrapositive, although they are logically equivalent to what you have done.

Comment: No, $\delta$ should depend on $\epsilon$ only and not $x$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta$ can't depend on $x$!

Assume that $|x-3|<\delta$, where $\delta$ is to be fixed, and is small enough 
so that $$|x-3|<\delta \implies 0<x<6$$ (so, $\delta < 3$).

Then using what you wrote in your message, when $|x−3| < \delta$:
$$
|x−3||x+3| \le \delta(x+3)\le 6\delta
$$

so taking $\delta = \min(\epsilon /  6,3)$ is convenient. Note that $\delta$ does depend only on $\epsilon$. This is the sightliest modification one can do to your proof to make it correct.

Comment: I don't see why $x+3\le3$.

Comment: Thanks - this is a nice solution.

Comment: @user84413 thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: Thank you for that. I have one additional question regarding your solution. I understand intuitively that assuming this : 

|x−3|<δ⟹0<x<6

(so, δ<3)

but I want to know algebraically is that because |x−3|<δ becomes -δ+3<x<δ+3?

Comment: indeed.${{{}}}$